# React Native Invariant Violation: "backdropFilter" is not a valid style property

Tags: react-native

I encounter this error message when I start my react native app: `Invariant Violation: "backdropFilter" is not a valid style property.` I checked that I don't have any `backdropFilter` used in my source code. But I still got this error.

full error message:

```
Invariant Violation: "backdropFilter" is not a valid style property.
StyleSheet generated: {
  "flexDirection": "column",
  "height": 68,
  "justifyContent": "center",
  "backgroundColor": "rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.82)",
  "backdropFilter": "blur(10px)",
  "paddingHorizontal": 24
}
Valid style props: [
  "alignContent",
  "alignItems",
  "alignSelf",
  "aspectRatio",
  "backfaceVisibility",
  "backgroundColor",
  "borderBottomColor",
  "borderBottomEndRadius",
  "borderBottomLeftRadius",
  "borderBottomRightRadius",
  "borderBottomStartRadius",
  "borderBottomWidth",
  "borderColor",
  "borderEndColor",
  "borderEndWidth",
  "borderLeftColor",
  "borderLeftWidth",
  "borderRadius",
  "borderRightColor",
  "borderRightWidth",
  "borderStartColor",
  "borderStartWidth",
  "borderStyle",
  "borderTopColor",
  "borderTopEndRadius",
  "borderTopLeftRadius",
  "borderTopRightRadius",
  "borderTopStartRadius",
  "borderTopWidth",
  "borderWidth",
  "bottom",
  "color",
  "decomposedMatrix",
  "direction",
  "display",
  "elevation",
  "end",
  "flex",
  "flexBasis",
  "flexDirection",
  "flexGrow",
  "flexShrink",
  "flexWrap",
  "fontFamily",
  "fontSize",
  "fontStyle",
  "fontVariant",
  "fontWeight",
  "height",
  "includeFontPadding",
  "justifyContent",
  "left",
  "letterSpacing",
  "lineHeight",
  "margin",
  "marginBottom",
  "marginEnd",
  "marginHorizontal",
  "marginLeft",
  "marginRight",
  "marginStart",
  "marginTop",
  "marginVertical",
  "maxHeight",
  "maxWidth",
  "minHeight",
  "minWidth",
  "opacity",
  "overflow",
  "overlayColor",
  "padding",
  "paddingBottom",
  "paddingEnd",
  "paddingHorizontal",
  "paddingLeft",
  "paddingRight",
  "paddingStart",
  "paddingTop",
  "paddingVertical",
  "position",
  "resizeMode",
  "right",
  "rotation",
  "scaleX",
  "scaleY",
  "shadowColor",
  "shadowOffset",
  "shadowOpacity",
  "shadowRadius",
  "start",
  "textAlign",
  "textAlignVertical",
  "textDecorationColor",
  "textDecorationLine",
  "textDecorationStyle",
  "textShadowColor",
  "textShadowOffset",
  "textShadowRadius",
  "textTransform",
  "tintColor",
  "top",
  "transform",
  "transformMatrix",
  "translateX",
  "translateY",
  "width",
  "writingDirection",
  "zIndex"
]

invariant
    browser.js:38:14
styleError
    StyleSheetValidation.js:77:11
validateStyleProp
    StyleSheetValidation.js:35:16
validateStyle
    StyleSheetValidation.js:55:6
module.exports.create
    StyleSheet.js:356:8
css
    emotion-primitives-core.browser.cjs.js:131:26
<global>
    styles.ts:58:16
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:321:11
<global>
    index.tsx:12
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:321:11
<global>
    index.tsx:12
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:321:11
<global>
    index.js:9
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:321:11
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:201:44
global code
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:226443:3
```

Here is my package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0-next.10",
    "@emotion/native": "^11.0.0-next.12",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.0.0-next.10",
    "@nozbe/watermelondb": "0.20.0",
    "@nozbe/with-observables": "^1.0.5",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.7",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.7.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.8.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.4.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.9",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.160",
    "@types/node-forge": "^0.9.5",
    "@welldone-software/why-did-you-render": "^4.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "crypto-js": "^3.3.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "node-forge": "^0.10.0",
    "observable-hooks": "^2.3.5",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-crypto": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-msal": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.6.0",
    "react-native-view-pdf": "^0.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.62.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.27.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript-prettier": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.13.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.2",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because backdropFilter is not one of the style props supported by react-native. You can remove it in you style sheet and the program should be able to work.